# How to target a specific div by knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

here i am pasting a code which slide toggle a child div but if parent div contains many child div and each child div has unique id then how could slide toggle a specific div by id using knockout js.

### here is full working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Step 2 - Include jquery and knockout -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Step 3 - Add script to run when page loads -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            <!-- Step 4 - Create a ViewModel -->
            function viewModel() {
                _self = this;
                _self.showHide = function(viewModel, event) {
                    $(event.currentTarget).children('div').slideToggle();
                };
            };

            <!-- Step 5 -  Activates knockout.js bindings -->
          ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="">
    <div>
        Option 1
        <!-- Step 6 - Create a HTML Elements with bindings -->
        <div data-bind="click: showHide" style="border:2px solid;">
        Click me
            <div style="display: none;">
              Now you see me!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

just see this line and tell me how could i slide toggle a specific child dib div by id

```
$(event.currentTarget).children('div').slideToggle();  thanks
```

Comment: None of your `<div>`s even have `id`s

Comment: suppose we can have multiple div with id like as `<div id="dv1" style="display: none;">
    Now you see me!
</div>
<div id="dv2" style="display: none;">
    Now you see me!
</div>` now tell me how to access a specific div by id

Comment: can we use this code to find div by id  `$(event.currentTarget).children('#idToFind').slideToggle();`  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try to avoid such actions in your code.

Proper way of doing what you want described here (fadeVisible binding): http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html

You simply need to add binding on node which need to be hidden/shown.

Comment: i just asked how to specify or access div by id.so see this code `$(event.currentTarget).children('div').slideToggle();` and tell me how to specify by id?